# How does one setup a private network with ethereum docker images?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, docker

I'm confused about how to get/access geth that is inside the container.

So far I have:

```
docker pull ethereum/client-go
```

it seems though that this image is designed to work on the public network. do i have to make my own dockerfile?

What do I need to include in that dockerfile and how do I access geth?

Should geth be installed on the 'host' os/where the image/containers are or can it be solely in the docker container?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a private network, you need to create your own genesis file (see the "Operating a private network" section of the documentation of the [client-go Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ethereum/client-go/).

If you create that in a folder, and then are on the command line in that folder, running:

```
docker run --name ethereum-node -v ${PWD}:/private-data \
   ethereum/client-go init /private-data/genesis.json
```

Should initialize the node.

Then you should be able to bring up the node with the command they give:

```
docker run -d --name ethereum-node -v /Users/alice/ethereum:/root \
   -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 \
   ethereum/client-go --fast --cache=512
```

If you want to attach to that running node to get at the Javascript CLI, do:

```
docker exec -it ethereum-node /user/bin/geth attach
```

Geth does *not* need to be installed on the host OS, it can just reside in the Docker container. If you want to control where the blockchain data gets saved, you can alter the `-v` commands to point to a different location in the host OS to store the data the container generates.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't realize the genesis.json could exist outside the image. i don't know why I thought it had to be part of the image. So I can further use the docker exec command to get geth to run the container as an executable? So could I do: 

`docker exec -it ethereum-node /user/bin/geth --version` 

and it'll show me the version of geth?

Comment: I don't think I can docker run with the second command. how do i get the container running after I init it?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on something like this, but not using the official images - https://github.com/the-chaingang/ethereal

If you have access to [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), you should be able to bring up a private network with a `docker-compose up`.

The Dockerfile and entrypoint code should help you get started re: geth installation, etc.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

We published a Docker container [here](https://github.com/CoinFabrik/DockerEthereum) and a tutorial of how to use it [here](https://blog.coinfabrik.com/dockerized-ethereum-private-testing-environment-compatible-with-metamask-and-remix/). This Ethereum environment can also be used with Remix and MetaMask to develop and debug smart contracts.